# I cannot call my methods from jframe

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I have a class called FrameRadar, it is a jframe and implements my interface app, which contains some methods such as update, draw and inputs and so on.

```
public class FrameRadar extends javax.swing.JFrame implements IApp{
    ...
}
```

However FrameRadar does not have the main method in it, instead i made another class called StateMenu, which extends a abstract class state. On it i created a jframe object and latter i initialize it.

```
class StateMenu extends State {

private JFrame mFrame;
...

public void init() {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mFrame = new FrameRadar();
                    mFrame.setVisible(true);
                }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that i was expecting mFrame to be able to call those method but it does not. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call the methods because there are no guarantees that mFrame is a FrameRadar. Either declare it as a FrameRadar, or you need to cast it to FrameRadar before calling the functions.

Comment: Thanks, it would take me hours to think of the obvious.